# I'm trying to upload an image on mongodb using POSTMAN the error says,"Cannot read property 'buffer' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I am trying to post an image and 3 other fields to store in my mongoDB atlas, the following is the code in my ROUTES file

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const keys = require('../config/key');
const passport = require('passport');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { ensureAuth, ensureAdmin } = require('../middleware/auth');
var multer = require('multer');

var storage = multer.memoryStorage();
var upload = multer({ storage: storage });

// @route   POST /novels
// @desc    Create novel
// @access  Private
router.post(
  '/',
  upload.single('image'),

  (req, res) => {
    const newNovel = new Novel({
      title: req.body.title,
      author: req.body.author,
      synopsis: req.body.synopsis,
    });
    newNovel.img.data = req.file.image.buffer;
    newNovel.img.contentType = 'image/jpg';

    console.log('boidy:', req.body);

    newNovel.save().then((novel) => res.json(novel));
  }
);
```

The following things I enter in the postman body-part, the image contains error and entered field[image: The postman image]

Here is my SCHEMA for the following

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const chapter = require('./Chapter');

const NovelSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  author: {
    type: String, //mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, // author object,
    required: true,
  },
  synopsis: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  comments: [
    {
      body: String,
      date: Date,
    },
  ],
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
  },
  access: {
    // true for public || false for private
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  noOfChapters: {
    type: Number,
  },
  ***img: { data: Buffer, contentType: String }***,
  Chapters: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Chapter',
    },
  ],
  genre: [String],
  meta: {
    views: {
      type: Number,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Number,
    },
  },
});

module.exports = Novel = mongoose.model('Novel', NovelSchema);
```

currently I am only adding TITLE,AUTHOR, and SYNOPSIS in my databse earlier I tried it without image and it worked just fine

Answer (score 0):

please do `console.log(req.file.image)` to check the value. If I'm not wrong, it should be `req.image.buffer`(without `.image`).

```
newNovel.img.data = req.file.buffer;
```